# IE 11 doesn't parse HTTP Content Disposition header correctly

Tags: python, utf-8, internet-explorer-11, content-disposition

I am trying to set Content Disposition header to get custom filename while performing file downloading in IE 11.

I've faced extremely strange behaviour in IE 11: when  escape (U+001B) char is present in filename of Content Disposition header IE 11 cannot set proper filename ( provided in Content Dispostion Header). For instance `content_disposition` with formatted `file_name_1` triggers IE 11 error, but formatting with `file_name_2` is fine:

```
# There are invisible control character escape (U+001B)
name = u'_$B!'
file_name_1 = quote(name) # gives "_%1B%24B%21"
file_name_2 = "_%24B%21.pdf"
content_disposition = "attachment; filename*=utf-8''%s" % file_name_2
```

Is there are any ways to provide support of any utf8 filename in IE11.

**Note**: In all other browsers everything seems to work fine and I hope there are way to fix IE 11 behaviour without breaking other browsers...

Comment: I don't understand - why would one want an *invisible* character in a file name in the first place? This could be a security filter of some sort.

Comment: @Pekka웃 place doesn't matter there %1B could be anywhere in file name, the problem is that in case if %1b present - file name would be incorrectly displayed. Also, I cannot control data which i would put as file name.

Comment: What file name are you getting instead in IE11?

Comment: @Pekka웃  File name has different value all the time ( my guess it depends on file download url as it's dynamic), for instance "afdCddNN%2BYK99Notq33ZzzDCiO9ngVJzYbNj1vV5bn9HlO90oSSTk0o7ermuKK%3D"

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for your attempt to help, your suggestion with filter. I've decided to strip all control codes chars prior forming Content Disposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to strip control characters prior forming content disposition header ( more info in @JulianReschke answer).

[Control codes](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) in python may be stripped easily with [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and [ord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

```
# There are invisible control character escape (U+001B)
name = u'_$B!'
# All chars with ord(s) <= 31 is a control characters.
name = "".join(i for i in name if ord(i) > 31)
```

So after adding line above to code, everything started to work fine:

```
name = u'_$B!'
# Strip control codes
name = "".join(i for i in name if ord(i) > 31)

file_name_1 = quote(name) # gives "_%1B%24B%21"
file_name_2 = "_%24B%21.pdf"
content_disposition = "attachment; filename*=utf-8''%s" % file_name_2
```

Answer (score 2):

Not accepting characters like these is actually what the specification recommends. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#rfc.section.4.3.p.5:

"Recipients SHOULD strip or replace character sequences that are known to cause confusion both in user interfaces and in filenames, such as control characters and leading and trailing whitespace."

Of course one could argue what keeping the remaining characters would be somehow better, but the important point is that User Agents are recommended to strip control characters.

Comment: You are right, most likely i will strip control chars if i wouldn't get any other option